# C# calling a function after WKWebView has loaded

Tags: c#, ios, webview

So I have this function that loads a request to the WKWebView, and what I'm trying to do is to call ShowWebViewer after the request has loaded. The problem is that invoke is calling this function instantly:

```
public void SetLink(string link)
 {
   WebViewer = new WKWebView(View.Frame, new WKWebViewConfiguration());
   WebViewer.SizeToFit();
   var url = NSUrlRequest.FromUrl(NSUrl.FromString(link));
   WebViewer.LoadRequest(url).Invoke(ShowWebViewer);
 }
```

Please help me, it's a simple answer but I couldn't find it anywhere

Answer (score 0):

So I have finally found an answer to this.
First of all, I had to create a class for WKNavigationDelegate like below, where I could add what to do after the request has loaded and others...

```
public class WebViewerNavigationDelegate : WKNavigationDelegate
    {

    }
```

And then, I attributed the class I created ( WebViewerNavigationDelegate ) to my WKWebKit.NavigationDelegate. This is the final code:

```
...

    public class WebViewerNavigationDelegate : WKNavigationDelegate
    {
        public override void DidFinishNavigation(WKWebView webView, WKNavigation navigation)
        {
           // anything you need to do after the navigation has loaded
        }
    }

    public void SetLink(string link)
    {
        WebViewer = new WKWebView(View.Frame, new WKWebViewConfiguration());
        var url = NSUrlRequest.FromUrl("url");
        WebViewer.NavigationDelegate = new WebViewerNavigationDelegate();
        WebViewer.LoadRequest(url);
    }
```